# PHP/HTML/JavaScript - Creating buttons with data attributes from PHP to HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have data in a PHP array I want to turn into buttons.

For simplicity, these buttons will `console.log()` their data on click.

Right now I'm using inline event handlers to do this.

How do I approach this problem using data attributes and no inline event handlers? I know how to create data attributes, but I don't know how to log the data and bind event listeners to the buttons.

```
<script>
    function logData(lat, long) {
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(long);
    }
</script>

<?php
$coordinates = array(
  first => array(
    "lat" => "64",
    "long" => "89"
  ),
  second => array(
    "lat" => "23",
    "long" => "11"
  ),
  third => array(
    "lat" => "35",
    "long" => "76"
  )
);
// Create buttons with inline event handlers
foreach($coordinates as $point) {
    echo "<button onclick='logData(".$point["lat"].", ".$point["long"].")'>Button</button>";
}

echo "<br><br>";
// Create buttons with data attributes. How do you log the data without inline event handlers?
foreach($coordinates as $point) {
    echo "<button data-lat=".$point["lat"]." data-long=".$point["long"].">Button</button>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give each button a way to identify them, like a `class` attribute value.

```
foreach($coordinates as $point) {
  echo '<button class="point-button" data-lat="' . $point["lat"]. '" data-long="' . $point["long"] . '">Button</button>';
}
```

In JavaScript select all buttons that have that specific class and listen for the `click` event for each individual button.

The fired click event gives information about the element that is being clicked. That reference is stored in the `target` property of the event object.

Now that you have the clicked button, read out the `dataset` property of the button. It should have properties for every `data-*` attribute on the element, without the `data-` part in the name. So, for example, `data-lat` is represented as `dataset.lat`.

```
// Log function.
function logData(lat, long) {
  console.log(lat, long);
}

// Get all buttons with the point-button class.
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.point-button');

// Click event handler
function onButtonClick(event) {
  const currentButton = event.target;
  const lat = currentButton.dataset.lat;
  const long = currentButton.dataset.long;

  logData(lat, long);
}

// For each button, add an event listener for the click event. 
// Call logData when a click happens.
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
});
```

Comment: Your first code segment has problems with quotes.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is exactly what I needed. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this

```js
function hello(event){
  alert(event.dataset.lat)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello(this)" data-lat="hello">
      save
</button>
```

in your case

```
foreach($coordinates as $point) {
  echo '<button class="point-button" data-lat="' . $point["lat"]. '" data-long="' . $point["long"] . '" onclick="loadData(this)">Button</button>';
}
```

and in js

```
function loadData(event) {
   const lat = event.dataset.lat
   const lon = event.dataset.long

   console.log(lat, long)
 
}
```